# Is SysRq still a thing?

Tags: server, 20.04, keyboard, sysrq

Reading this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html

I've been trying to use this on an ubuntu server VM to see what I can do, but I can't find the key combo. Could it be that Ubuntu server ISO are compiled without support for this?

If not, it seems that the keyboard needs a SysRq key? Which I don't seem to have. The article claims that the Print Screen button can be used, but that just immediately takes a screenshot.

This is on an x86 system.

So, what's going on here? Should I be able to use this, or am I missing something?

EDIT: Host OS is Win10, using Virtualbox 7.0.6

EDIT2: Verified the server has sysrq enabled:

```
~$ sudo sysctl -a | grep sysrq
kernel.sysrq = 176
```

Comment: No, it got replaced, long ago, by alt-prtsc.

Comment: What is your host OS? How is the virtualization software configured to pass special keys?

Comment: I use SysRq commands somewhat frequently; however some Ubuntu products/releases have the key disabled by default though most releases of Ubuntu do have some SysRq functions *enabled* but some features are *disabled* for some releases but not others. Ubuntu 20.04 has few restrictions though (*SysRq functions being disabled is in more recent releases for Desktop installs anyway*).  SysRq never was a single key; it was always written on the FRONT of a key (usually PrntScr but note not the top of key!) & still exists but that's rare given the flat nature of todays keys & front isn't seen.

Comment: FYI:  I've had no issues using SysRq on devices as new as 2021 (ie. ~two years old) though on some I need to use three keys, ie. Fn+Alt+Sysrq (where SysRq isn't always visible but it's the usual key, just the keys being flat they don't print it on the front of the key which wouldn't be seen thus on the 2021 Dell it's Fn+Alt+Insert/PrintScr) but device *firmware* will dictate which key and if Fn is required (*modern keyboards often use keys for multiple functions like the device I looked at has Insert+PrintScreen use same key)

Comment: @guiverc Tried all that, not working. Verified that it is enabled on the server I'm trying it on. I'll keep looking. `~$ sudo sysctl -a | grep sysrq
kernel.sysrq = 176`

Comment: Your issue maybe your windows OS & virtualbox setting... as it will control what keys actually get thru to your VM, however if you refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic you'll note windows 10 is not an on-topic OS.